# Local git ssh into server using Tower

Tags: git, ssh, nano

I'm new to git, i've always used FTP but someone told me that this is the best way to go and i'm keen to give it a try so i'm trying to set it up but having an issue.

Rather than use github etc, i've decided to have a local git and then push that to my server.

I'm using macOS sierra, Terminal and Tower for reference.

I'll tell you what i'm currently doing and hopefully someone can tell me what i've done wrong.

Firstly I now need to enable SSH on my hosting account, this will give me a username, server and password.

First things first, I need to setup an SSH connection, I open terminal and type the following:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa

/Users/myusername/.ssh/id_rsa
```

I'll then press enter, enter, enter and it will generate a key. I now need to copy that to the server so I type the following in to terminal:

```
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub username@server
```

I then enter my password

Once done, I enter:

```
ssh username@server
```

and i'm connected via SSH.

I now type into terminal:

```
PWD
```

to get my serverurl i.e. /var/sites/u/site.com

I'll keep a note of this for the moment.

I now want to create a git folder so I type the following into terminal while connected via SSH:

```
mkdir website.git && cd website.git

git init --bare

nano hooks/post-receive
```

I now type the following into nano replacing serverurl with the output of PWD

```
#!/bin/sh 
GIT_WORK_TREE=serverurl git checkout -f
```

I then save and exit nano.

I now type

```
chmod 755 hooks/post-receive
```

and then quit terminal.

I now open Tower, create a local git repository called website, once done i open the repository in Tower and click open remote repository.

I then name it dev and use the following for the remote url

```
ssh://username@server/serverurl/website.git
```

finally click add remote. It then seems to validate ok.

The above seems to work as far as I can tell.

If i add for instance a html file called index.html to the local website folder i can see it in Tower ok.

I then edit the html, save, open tower and give it a commit, once done I push it to the server and it seems to work but there are no changes to the index.html file on my website.

I can't see what i've done wrong, can anyone help?